# Can't run blender

Tags: linux

Blender suddenly stopped working on my PC.
Can anyone help me pls.

When i try to run it. I get following error

blender: error while loading shared libraries: libncursesw.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Sounds like the kind of problem that may require uninstalling and reinstalling Blender. I'm not speaking from experience, it's just that if library files are missing or corrupt, your installation could have problems with it... or there could be problems with your hard drive. It's hard to say.

Comment: I tried uninstalling  but it didn't work.